# Create global array to access from all components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to reactjs. I have an array of objects, I want this array to be global and be accessed from multiple components. How do I handle this? Do I create another class and then import it?

FYI in Angular I would've created a service containing this array to have access from all components.

```
carts = [
        {
            title: 'Travel',
            backgroundColor: '#796157',
            description: 'Keep your eyes fresh & travel to other countries.',
            image: hs1,
            gallery: [
                '/assets/images/capture_1_travel/4.jpg',
                '/assets/images/capture_1_travel/2.jpg',
                '/assets/images/capture_1_travel/3.PNG'
            ]
        },
        {
            title: 'Record',
            backgroundColor: '#8693A2',
            description: 'Record the most important moments.',
            image: hs2,
            gallery: [
                '/assets/images/capture_3_record/2.jpg',
                '/assets/images/capture_3_record/5.jpg',
                '/assets/images/capture_3_record/3.jpg',
                '/assets/images/capture_3_record/4.jpg',
                '/assets/images/capture_3_record/6.jpg'
            ]
        },
        ...
```

Comment: use a state manager then you can access to all you need via store or if you dont want to use state manager like redux you can use it via props Inheritance from parents component

Comment: Will you change this array in your app? If yes, then easy "export" is a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to put this in a file called `data.js` and change the array to  be `export const carts = [...]`. Then you can import it into any js react file with `import { carts } from './data.json';`

Answer (score 0):

1. Context https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html
2. Redux library
3. Use "state" and push array to children components with "props".

Answer (score 0):

Though I won't recommend using it, you could atach `carts` to `window` object, such as:

```
window.carts=[...]
```